# Removing/adding an object from/to scene in three.js

Tags: three.js

I am trying to add or remove an object from scene:

```
const rootObject = this.scene.getObjectByName('Object Group');
rootObject.remove(obj);// OR rootObject.add(obj);
```

What I observe is that to make change visible in scene, user needs to perform some action, like panning or zoomin/out etc.

How can change be made visible immediately without needing a manual action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the scene is being redrawn not in the animation loop, but in some events (click, panning or zoomin/out, etc.).

So when adding or removing an object, you need to force a frame to be rendered. For example:

```
document
  .getElementById('toggle')
  .addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (obj) {
      removeObject()
    } else {
      addObject()
    }
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  })
```

[ https://jsfiddle.net/xmke5u20/ ]

Comment: 'It looks like the scene is being redrawn not in the animation loop'...it got me to root cause. Thanks.